# JS scripts not loading on certain pages

Tags: 8, commerce, javascript

When logged in as a user (not admin), some JS scripts do not load on certain pages.

I found out about this issue because I am using the module [EU Cookie Compliance](https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance) and the scripts it uses (`eu_cookie_compliance.js`, `jquery.cookie.shim.js`, `js.cookie.min.js`) aren't always loaded.

I am using a JS method provided by the EU Cookie Compliance module in my custom theme and found out it triggered an error on some pages (because the scripts aren't loaded).

For example, the scripts load on `/user/2` but don't on `/user/2/orders` or `/user/2/customer` as you can see on the below image. **Why does this happen?**

[image]

I can see no option in EU Cookie Compliance module that prevents loading the script on some pages. Nor did I find anything in the code.

- Drupal core: 8.9.3
- [EU Cookie Compliance](https://www.drupal.org/project/eu_cookie_compliance): 8.x-1.9

#### Edit:

I have now included `eu_cookie_compliance` as a dependency in my theme:

```
dependencies:
  - core/drupal
  - core/jquery
  - core/jquery.once
  - core/drupalSettings
  - eu_cookie_compliance/eu_cookie_compliance
  - eu_cookie_compliance/eu_cookie_compliance_bare
```

And this fixed the fact that the scripts weren't loaded on all pages. That said, I now have errors on these specific pages.

All I do in my theme's JS (`radix_sub.script.js`) is using `Drupal.eu_cookie_compliance.hasAgreed()` which now triggers the following errors:

[image]

I have tried declaring only `eu_cookie_compliance` and only `eu_cookie_compliance_bare` and both in my theme libraries, and the errors are identical.

Comment: Yeah, it's not loading on some pages because 1. It's not required for those pages. Or 2. There's a bug in the module somewhere. I'm guessing it's #1. (p.s. sorry, deleted earlier comment to post as answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's not loading on some pages, but ultimately it's because the library isn't required for those pages. If a module's library is required by your theme then you need to declare it as a dependency.

You can do this for your library in your theme's *libraries.yml* file. See the [Declaring dependencies documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#s-declaring-dependencies).

```
# my_theme.libraries.yml
# It's not clear if you want the bare or full cookie compliance library
my_library:
  js:
    js/my_libary.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - eu_cookie_compliance/eu_cookie_compliance
    - eu_cookie_compliance/eu_cookie_compliance_bare
```

Comment: Ok, that's weird. You are right, declaring these as dependencies in my theme *fixes* the fact that the EU Cookie Compliance module scripts aren't loaded on all pages. But it now triggers other errors on those specific pages, and the style that I applied to the cookie compliance banner provided by the module aren't applied anymore.

Comment: Don't include both libraries as dependencies. I wasn't sure which one you wanted so I showed both. It sounds like you probably want the bare library

Comment: Please see the edit in my question. I have tried with both dependencies, or only `eu_cookie_compliance` or only `eu_cookie_compliance_bare` and the errors are identical.

Comment: Out of ideas, I also tried switching to the DEV version of the module and the problem is the same (not loading on the pages I mentioned).

Comment: You need to debug the console error message you get when the library is included on those extra pages.

Comment: I actually found out that `/install/eu_cookie_compliance.settings.yml` includes the following: `exclude_paths: "/admin\n/admin/*\n/batch\n/node/add*\n/node/*/*\n/user/*/*"` which is a configuration option that isn't available through the module UI. I had to export the configuration item, modify this line (remove `user/*/*`) and import it again and it now works as expected. The script is loaded on user pages and no more errors.